# Fluent NHibernate mapping: one table, many classes

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, mapping

How would I go about mapping three classes to one table with fluent NHibernate. A "Type" column should indicate which class should be mapped. Is it even possble?

- Kristoffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible, assuming that your classes extend a common base class. This is called table-per-class strategy and instructions on how to map it are in the [documentation](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping).

Comment: Thanks! The're is an example of it at the end of the documentation.

The properties are not virtual in the documentation, but they must be.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a situation where your data could be normalized? What you're trying to do seems like a dead giveaway that this is the actual problem.

Comment: Well, I'm basically just curious. I was thinking about how I could denormalize the database (for increased performance) without touching the object model.